# count matrix from a txt file, grep -c for a tab delimited file?

Tags: grep, text-formatting

I have a text file, here's the `head` of it:

```
1   TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGT  miRNA   mmu-mir-10b PM
2   GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCCT    tRNA    Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-4-1   PM
3   TACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGT  miRNA   mmu-mir-10a PM
4   GCATTGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCCT tRNA    Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-2-2   IM
5   ACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGT   other   other   NA
6   TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTG   other   other   NA
7   GCATTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCCT   tRNA    Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-2-7   IM
8   GCATTTGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCCT    tRNA    Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-4-1   IM
9   TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGTG miRNA   mmu-mir-10b PM
10  GGTGAATATAGTTTACAAAAAACATTAGACTGTGAATC  tRNA    tRNA-His    IM
```

I'd like a count matrix based on the 4th value in each line such that I have something like

```
mmu-mir-10b 2
```

Comment: This seems more like a job for a decent scripting language.

Comment: I am sorry, but it is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`, in case you want to get all duplicated located in position #4 (assuming data delimited by whitespaces):

```
$ awk '{seen[$4]++} END{for(x in seen) print x, seen[x]}' infile
other 2
Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-2-2 1
Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-2-7 1
mmu-mir-10a 1
mmu-mir-10b 2
tRNA-His 1
Mus_musculus_tRNA-Gly-GCC-4-1 2
```

First fields are the data and second filed is corresponding duplicates of that.

Comment: What would I do if I also wanted keep the 2nd item/column in the list?

Comment: You mean unique values based on both column2&4?then use `seen[$4FS$2]++` instead